# Python 3 - call a method to change another method in a class

Tags: methods

**Trying to make a class where i can make a dog stop and come**

And I'm struggling with what to write in my status method and also how to make the status call's output change when you call the comeHere() and stop() method

```
class Dog:
    def setYear(self, i):
        if len(i) == 4:
            self.__year = i


    def getYear(self):
        return self.__year


    def status(self):

    def comeHere(self):

    def stop(self):


def main():
    watson = Dog()
    watson.setYear(2011)
    print("The dog is born in ",watson.getYear())
    print(watson.status())
    print("trying to make the dog come")
    watson.comehere()
    print("Come here boy... ",watson.status())
    print("Trying to make him stop again")
    watson.stop()
    print("Stop! ... ",watson.status())

main()
```

## Want the output to be like this

```
The dog is born in 2011 

The dog is standing

Trying to make the dog to come

Come here boy... the dog is coming

Trying to make him stop again

Stop! ... The dog is standing
```

How do I call the status method and make the output change depended on the call before `status()`

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use status as variable not function

```
class Dog:

    def __init__(self):
        self.status="The dog is standing"
    def setYear(self, i):
        if len(str(i)) == 4:
            self.__year = i


    def getYear(self):

        return self.__year

    def comeHere(self):

        self.status="the dog is coming"

    def stop(self):
        self.status="The dog is standing"

watson = Dog()
watson.setYear(2011)
print("The dog is born in ",watson.getYear())
print(watson.status)
print("trying to make the dog come")
watson.comeHere()
print("Come here boy... ",watson.status)
print("Trying to make him stop again")
watson.stop()
print("Stop! ... ",watson.status)
```

output

```
The dog is born in  2011
The dog is standing
trying to make the dog come
Come here boy...  the dog is coming
Trying to make him stop again
Stop! ...  The dog is standing
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make `status` an variable in `Dog` class and modify it when one of the functions is called.

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.status = None

    def setYear(self, i):
        if len(i) == 4:
            self.__year = i

    def comeHere(self):
        self.status = "Dog is coming"

watson = Dog()
watson.comeHere()
print(watson.status) # returns 'Dog is coming"
```